# prove $\frac {x}{ay+bz} + \frac {y}{az+bx} + \frac {z}{ax+by} \geq \frac {3}{a+b}$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

show that$$\frac {x}{ay+bz} + \frac {y}{az+bx} + \frac {z}{ax+by} \geq \frac {3}{a+b}$$ 
using Cauchy inequality i can write $$(\frac {x}{ay+bz} + \frac {y}{az+bx} + \frac {z}{ax+by}) \times ((ay+bz)x+(az+bx)y+(ax+by)z)\geq (x+y+z)^2$$
$$(\frac {x}{ay+bz} + \frac {y}{az+bx} + \frac {z}{ax+by}) \times (axy+bxz+ayz+byx+azx+byz)\geq (x+y+z)^2$$
$$(\frac {x}{ay+bz} + \frac {y}{az+bx} + \frac {z}{ax+by}) \times (a+b)(xy+yz+zx)\geq (x+y+z)^2$$
$$(\frac {x}{ay+bz} + \frac {y}{az+bx} + \frac {z}{ax+by})\geq \frac {1}{a+b} \times \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{xy+yz+zx}$$
if i can show that $\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{xy+yz+zx} \geq 3$ then the problem is solved
how can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following identity
\begin{align*}
(x+y+z)^2-3(xy+xz+yz)=((x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2)/2,
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{xy+xz+yz}=3+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2}{xy+xz+yz}\geq 3.
\end{align*}

Comment: would have been nicer if you put some explanation.i would accept it even if you don't edit it.(other people may see this may not understand)